# Android Location API weird behavior

Tags: java, android, geolocation, android-location, fusedlocationproviderapi

I'm trying to fetch accurate location data for our android app and experiencing strange behavior of Location API (both old LocationListener API and new Fused Location API).

I'm getting location changes for a certain amount of time (half a minute from the app start) trying to get the most accurate data available in this time interval.

In case of LocationListener API everything is great until I use Google Maps in my Fragment. Without map location changes are frequent and accuracy is good, but when Map is shown, location frequency and accuracy are strongly affected.

setMyLocationEnabled(boolean) is set to false;

In case of Fused API I'm getting 10m accuracy inside any building, that's very weird too.

Btw I can't use latest versions of Google Play Services because of backward compatibility with other parts of the app.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: *Thanks in advance for any assistance.* with what? You told a story, what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that both APIs provide inaccurate data and I can't release a new version of the app. Also I can't get rid of a map, it's a requirement.

Comment: You might need to provide some code samples of how you are implementing both.